# Data from socket.recv() printing as a mixture of \x and printable ASCII, how to force raw hex?

Tags: python, tcp

I have some simple code which is listening to data on a TCP socket:

```
    data = client_socket.recv(4096)
    print("RECEIVED:",data)
```

It works great, but the output looks like this:

```
RECEIVED: b'\xd8\xff\xfe\x00$\xe3J\xda*\x00
```

and so on.

What I want is just the raw hex, like

```
D8 FF FE 00 24 E3 4A DA 2A 00
```

My end goal is to put the raw bytes straight into a file, but I do want to print them first.  How do I print them as I desire, and how do I put them into a file?  Maybe I do not even need to manipulate 'data' to put it in a file?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import binascii
binascii.hexlify('\xd8\xff\xfe\x00$\xe3J\xda*\x00').upper()
```

gets you most of the way ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  How can I make it work inline with the data variable?  I tried print("RECEIVED:",binascii.hexlify(data).upper()) but it crashed... DUH nevermind, I forgot to import binascii.  This worked great, accepting as solution soon.

Comment: can you help me byteswap the output?  instead of "d8fffe00" i need "ffd800fe"

Comment: it sounds like what you actually want is struct unpack ... take a look there